# $\sin (n \pi)=0 \ \ \ \ :\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that (Algebraic)

$$\sin (n \pi)=0, \ \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\sin \left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)=(-1)^n, \ \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\cos (n \pi)=(-1)^n, \ \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\sin \left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)=0, \ \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I can prove it using geometry . But I can not prove algebraically please help me thank you .

Comment: This highly depends on your definition of sine/cosine and what facts you know about them.

Comment: Then, you have to define $\sin$ without geometry, first. There are several possibilities (Taylor series, differential equations,...), but you have to choose one. If you don't want Euklid's axioms, say what is your alternative.

Comment: Give **your** (non-geometrical, apparently) definition of the functions $\;\sin x,\,\cos x\;$ and etc.

Comment: You can use induction but also in this case it is necessary to start from the basic definition. I really don't understand exactly what yuo are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept euler's formula:

$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ while $e^{-ix}=\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$

From this, you can recover that

$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
and
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

For cosine:

$$\frac{e^{in \pi}+e^{-i n \pi}}{2}=\frac{\exp(i \pi)^n+\exp(-i \pi)^n}{2}=\frac{(-1)^n+(-1)^n}{2}$$

and similar tricks work for the rest.

Comment: Note that euler's formula is either trivial or requires proof depending on the definition of $\sin,\cos$ you take.